# image display in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am displaying image from the sdcard. I searched a lot in google and got the following code

I have a button, on click of that I am calling camera feature.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {


                // create intent with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE action

         Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
            photoPath = Uri.fromFile(photo);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(photo));

            System.out.println(photoPath);
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
```

and I have wriiten following code in onActivityResult function.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {

     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

     if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                System.out.println("after activity"+photoPath);
                Uri selectedImage = photoPath;
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
                ivThumbnailPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivThumbnailPhoto);
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                Bitmap bitmap;
                try {
                     bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                     .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                     ivThumbnailPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
                }

            }

}
```

Problem is I am getting photoPath value as null and it ends up with nullpointer exception. Please help me to find out issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Debug it to see if the pic is properly loaded etc

Comment: Plase do not downvote as I am new to android and I have tried a lot, after that I am posting here

Comment: @TimCastelijn pic is stored properly in sdcard but still I am getting null value for that

Comment: Is `photo` null, too?

Comment: No, photo and photoPath have values in onClick event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a value of file path as intent extra, this is the correct behavior.

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(photo));//here  save this uri you are passing as extra.
```

in `onActivityResult`, if `RESULT_CODE` is `OK` use above `URI` which you passed in as `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, you will get null intent/data from camera, so don't use it.

**EDIT:-** as you are going out of activity and coming back there can be chances of your PhotoPath variable to become NULL, you have two solution here.

1) Make photopath/uri static.

2) Use below code to save it when going out and get the value when coming into the activity.

```
/**
 * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
 * app
 */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", photopath);
}

/*
 * Here we restore the fileUri again
 */
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the path
    photoPath = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}
```

Comment: I am following same method    photoPath = Uri.fromFile(photo); intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(photo));

Comment: would you mind checking the answer again, edited as par your problem.

Comment: Welcome, did you make it Static or added the data into Bundle/via methods?